# C++: Inheritance, linking (and dynamic libraries)

Tags: c++, inheritance, dll

I have the following MWE:

```
// classes.hpp
#pragma once

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void tell() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived() = default;
    ~Derived() = default;
    void tell() override;
};
```

then,

```
// classes.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.hpp"

extern "C" {
Derived* instantiate()
{
    return new Derived{};
}

void deinstantiate(Derived* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
}
}

void Derived::tell()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

which I compile on a linux machine as a shared library `g++ -fPIC -shared -o classes.so classes.cpp` and the main program:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "classes.hpp"


int main()
{
    using inst_t = Derived*(*)(void);
    using deinst_t = void(*)(Derived*);

    void* handle = dlopen("./classes.so", RTLD_NOW);
    inst_t inst = reinterpret_cast<inst_t>(dlsym(handle, "instantiate"));
    deinst_t deinst = reinterpret_cast<deinst_t>(dlsym(handle, "deinstantiate"));
    // some tests here...

    Derived* instance = inst();
    instance->tell();
    deinst(instance);
    dlclose(handle);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which I compile with `g++ -ldl -o main main.cpp`

It works well. However If I remove the inheritance of `Derived` from `Base`, i.e. if I substitute above `calsses.hpp` file with

```
// new classes.hpp
#pragma once

struct Derived {
    Derived() = default;
    ~Derived() = default;
    void tell();
};
```

I got a link error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLuFAZr.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `Derived::tell()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which I is sensible since it cannot find the symbol from `classes.cpp`.
However it is not completely clear to me how subclassing `Derived` from `Base` can solve this problem since `Base` is not used at all. (I think it should be a matter o vtable creation). So

1. How is it possible?
2. Is there any other way to solve the problem without using (dummy) inheritance?

## EDIT

Of course the cause of a linking error can be found in a question whose answers [list all the possible cause of linking errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). However, in my opinion this question is by far more generic than mine which deals with a particular situation (the use of dynamic shared library, ecc).

## EDIT 2

**Non-question**: Why, without inheritance, do I get link error? (I know)

**Question**: Why using inheritance do I not get link error?

Comment: Yes, I rebuild both main.cpp and classes.cpp

Answer (score 1):

`void Derived::tell()` is defined in `libclasses.so`.

With `#include "classes.hpp"`, the class is defined in main.cc, `instance->tell();` is an attempt to call `void Derived::tell()` defined in `main`, and the member function is not defined there for sure.

You might load the symbol `void Derived::tell()` from `libclasses.so` and call it like below:

```
// Derived::tell() is the _ZN7Derived4tellEv mangled name.
void (Derived::*tell)() = reinterpret_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(dlsym(handle, "_ZN7Derived4tellEv"));
(instance->*tell)();
```

Unfortunately the cast a pointer to a member function pointer is not allowed. You should wrap a member call into a regular function in libclasses.so:

```
extern "C" void call_tell(Derived* d) {
  d->tell();
}
```

```
auto* tell = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Derived* d)>(dlsym(handle, "call_tell"));
tell(instance);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I do not understand is why with a vtable it works.

Comment: But how can this vtable be looked for in `main` program which is another compilation unit?

Comment: If you call `new Derived{}` in main you get the error again. `inst()` doesn't look for vtbl in main.

Comment: This I understand. What I still do not understand is how it is possible, since the vtable is defined in `classes.so`, that it can be looked for in `main` with the instruction `instance->tell()`.

Comment: Do you mean that the `main` is aware of the vtable since vtable are build using declaration and not definition?

Comment: Yes, main is aware of `vtbl` structure.

Comment: But once it is aware, vtable, i think, should contain a pointer to `Derived::tell()` which is defined in `classes.so`. How can the vtable known by `main` program know the location of `classes.so`?

Comment: `main` has incomplete vtbl, it's just a pointer, `inst()` SETS the pointer to the complete vtbl from .so. main DOES NOT SET vtbl. Please stop going in circle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "void tell();" from Derived as "virtual void tell();". The derived should be:

```
struct Derived {
  Derived() = default;
  ~Derived() = default;
  virtual void tell();
```

};

Comment: This works, but why? Why it seems mandatory to create a virtual table?

Comment: Yes, but where the information of the vtbl are stored? How can the vtbl locate the symbol?

Comment: Answer could do with a bit more meat. WHY does making `tell` virtual solve the problem?

Comment: The `Derived` class has its only `tell` method defined in the `classes.so` library. However, this class was declared in `main` without any method defined. When you call `instance->tell()` in main, it doesn't have a defined method to execute. If you declare this virtual method, the program can pass execution to `tell()` in `classes.o`.

Comment: But there are two separate compilation unit. Is it guaranteed that the two vtbl correspond?

Comment: I checked the `classes.so` symbol table, the `tell()` method is there with or without the `virtual` modifier. It is only necessary so that the `main` program (which does not have `tell()` defined) can pass on to the external library `classes.so` to execute this method. To see the `classes.o` symbols `objdump -T classes.so`. The answer is yes, they will match.